# Clojure - Splitting a vector

Tags: clojure

If I have two arguments [[1 2] [3 4]] and [5 6], how can I get to [[1 5] [2 6] [3 5] [4 6]].

I thought I may have to use `for` so I tried,

```
(for [x [[1 2] [3 4]]] 
  (for [xx x] 
    (for [y [5 6]] [xx y])))
```

But it returned `((([1 5] [1 6]) ([2 5] [2 6])) (([3 5] [3 6]) ([4 5] [4 6])))`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
(mapcat #(map vector % [5 6]) [[1 2] [3 4]])
```

or using `for`:

```
(for [c [[1 2] [3 4]]
      p (map vector c [5 6])]
  p)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, your solution is actually very close. You did not need to nest the `for` expressions explicitly, since doing so creates a new list at every level, instead, just use multiple bindings:

```
(for [x [[1 2][3 4]]
      xx x
      y [5 6]]
  [xx y])
```

Which will result in

```
([1 5] [1 6] [2 5] [2 6] [3 5] [3 6] [4 5] [4 6])
```

### Edit

Now that I finally read your question carefully, I came up with the same answer as @Lee did `(mapcat (fn[x] (map vector x [5 6])) [[1 2] [3 4]])`, which is the right one and should probably be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This is one (hmm - not particularly elegant) way to get your answer, without using `for`:

```
(defn f [x y]
  (let [x' (apply concat x)
        multiples (/ (count x') (count y))
        y' (apply concat (repeat multiples y))]
    (mapv vector x' y')))

(f [[1 2] [3 4]] [5 6])
;;=> [[1 5] [2 6] [3 5] [4 6]]
```