# Clojure - Combining Two vectors into a vector of vectors

Tags: clojure

How can I combine `[[1 2] [3 4]]` and `[5 6]` to get `[[1 5] [2 5] [3 6] [4 6]]`

I tried `(map vector [[1 2] [3 4]] [5 6])` but the result was `([[1 2] 5] [[3 4] 6])`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is this question for an assignment?

Comment: You already asked this here [Clojure - Splitting a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44156063/clojure-splitting-a-vector), and got a few answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mapcat` and an inner `map` like this:

```
user=> (mapcat (fn [as b] 
                 (mapv #(vector % b) as)) 
         [[1 2] [3 4]] [5 6])
([1 5] [2 5] [3 6] [4 6])
```